# Importing Weka to Eclipse

Tags: java, weka

I'm trying to use Weka in Eclipse. I've already imported the "weka-src.jar" to my project and it's currently in the "Referenced Libraries" folder, but it still says "The import weka cannot be resolved."

Is there something else that I need to do here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the **`weka.jar`** file from the directory where your WEKA distribution is located on your computer as well.

---

Note: To make use of things like [**MTJ**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_Toolkit_Java) in your project you need to expand the **`weka.jar`** file that's inside the WEKA distribution you have downloaded and add the following files to your project as separate library **`.jar`** files:

- **`mtj.jar`**
- **`arpack_combined_all.jar`**
- **`core.jar`**

You can expand a **`.jar`** file using unzip utilities (a **`.jar`** file is basically a **`.zip`** file), or you can use the jar utility that comes with the JDK:

```
jar -xf weka.jar
```

Basically, sometimes it is not sufficient to just add **`weka.jar`** as a library.